# How to do 'busy' animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, busy-cursor, busyindicator

Doesn't seem to be covered in the books Ive looked at.

Comment: please refer this URL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025652/android-activity-indicator/13626227#13626227

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to the progress dialogs described in the other answers, you can:

- Add a `ProgressBar` to your activity, as shown [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Threads/Handler/)
- Use the progress indicator in the title bar of your activity, as shown [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/08-Threads/LunchList/)
- Use a `RotateAnimation` and your own custom image

Comment: I see setProgressBarVisibility() in one of your examples - how do you define the style of the progress bar? I wanted to use the spinning circular graphic but Im not sure how to set that?

Comment: I haven't used it. But, try this: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ProgressBar2.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a progress dialog: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html